# Object Tracking with Simulink

Tags: pi-2, bash, matlab

I am currently utilising the Simulink Hardware Support Package for the RPi to implement an object tracking and pan-tilt algorithm. The issue I am coming up against at the moment is I cannot find a way to either:

- Write to a file on the Pi from simulink (to enable a local python script to use servoblaster), *or...*
- Send command line (bash) inputs to the pi to control the servos straight from Simulink.

Obviously a quick solution would be to move my detection algorithm from simulink and into python on the pi, but OpenCV is not an options for many reasons I'd rather not get into. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UDP Receive blocks in your model to receive commands from an external application, the Linux shell or MATLAB for example. To receive commands from the bash shell, set the IP Address of the UDP Receive block to '127.0.0.1' (i.e. localhost) and bind it to an unused port. Let's say this is 8000. Once you start running the Simulink model on your Raspberry Pi hardware, you can send commands to your Simulink model using bash shell:

$ echo -n "right" >/dev/udp/localhost/8000

I wrote a servoblaster device driver block for Raspberry Pi at some point in the past. Post this question in MATLAB Answers for source code.

Comment: This is a brilliant solution! I came up with the idea to implement a hardware version of this by simpling linking the Pi's GPIO's in input-output pairs so that the Pi could talk to itself. I like your solution better. Thanks so much! I'll post over in MATLAB Answers to see if I can find any more support.